# How can i call make file from other directory

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, makefile

I have directory structure like this

```
containers/con1
containers/con2
containers/con3
```

Now every folder like con1, con2 has Makefile in it with targets like `build, run`

I run it like `make run` and `make build`

But i have to go inside that folder.

Is it possible that i have another `Makefile` in `containers/Makefile`

and i can run like

`Make con1.run` `Make con2.run`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Something like the following should do what you want.

```
$ cat containers/Makefile
%.run: %
        $(MAKE) -C $@
```

That being said as you can see the command to do what you want is trivial enough to make such a makefile not really necessary (and a simple shell script is as useful here as a makefile).

```
$ cat run.sh
[ -d "$1" ] || { echo 'No such directory.' >&2; exit 1; }
#make -C "$1"
# OR
#cd "$1" && make
```

If you wanted to be able to build *all* the sub-directory projects at once then a makefile could help you with that but even that is a simple enough shell one-liner.

```
$ for mkfile in */Makefile; do make -C "$(dirname "$mkfile"); done
$ for mkfile in */Makefile; do (cd "$(dirname "$mkfile") && make); done
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want this:

```
   -C dir, --directory=dir
        Change to directory dir before reading the makefiles or doing anything else.  If multiple -C options are specified, each is interpreted relative to the previous one: -C / -C etc is equivalent to -C /etc.   This  is  typi‐
        cally used with recursive invocations of make.
```

Add `-C` option like this: `make -C con1/`

Answer (score 0):

Recursive makes are evil, but if you want that:

```
# con1.run is a phony target...
.PHONY: con1.run

con1.run:
    $(MAKE) -C con1
```